# check whether the MDIcontainer is empty or not

Tags: c#, winforms

I just stuck in a very simple situation bt couldnt help myself.My question is
How to do i check whether my mdiparent contains the child form or not?
help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ActiveMdiChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activemdichild.aspx) property of your parent form.

It will be `null` if the parent does not contain any MDI child form.

Answer (score 1):

For the title of your question:

```
int formCount = this.MdiChildren.Count(); \\ or .Length
MessageBox.Show("I have " + formCount.ToString() + " child forms open.");
```

For the other part of your question:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.MdiParent = this;
f2.Show();

if (this.MdiChildren.Contains(f2))
  MessageBox.Show("Form2 f2 is opened");
```